# authorisation with paypal sandbox curl

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I developed my script with PayPal APIs RESTful for payments.
On my local computer, it works great!
But not on my website :( and I don't undestand why.
It' the curl fonction which seems to be the problem.

Here's a part of my code in PHP :

```
<?php
$id = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
$secret = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";   
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");  //DUMMY
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $id . ":" . $secret);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);

echo '<br>ch='.$ch;
echo '<br>r='.print_r($result,1);
curl_close ($ch);
```

On my local server, it returns the following response:

> ch=Resource id #2 r={"scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture
>   https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts
>   https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer
>   https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card openid
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller
>   https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment","nonce":"2018-06-23T12:52:59Zi8vohQXD6WC0NzGJDDmOYY3C94kgmEfORAs9lAMxBW0","access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":32078}

Cool! :)

But on my website, it returns :

> ch=Resource id #2 r=

Why ? I really don't understand :(((

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hai vincent, what error did you get, when you run this code in website,

Comment: Add in an `echo curl_error($ch);` ... see if it has anything extra.

Comment: this line does not look good :) `echo '<br>r='.print_r($result,1);` does it work exactly like this on your localhost? try like this: `echo '<br>r='.$result;` maybe your code is ok, and the error is in writing things to the output..

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, I find the problem
On my website, i had Openssl 0.9 version and with paypal i have to be on Opennssl 1.0 version...